# How to force a desired numeration of equations in Book/Monograph StyleSheet?

Tags: notebooks, stylesheet, text-formatting

I am writing a text in the MMA > Format > StyleSheet > Book > Monograph StyleSheet. I have a problem with the automatic numeration of `"EquationNumbered"` cells.

Namely, I have several `"BookChapterTitle"`. These are numbered but not necessarily starting from one, and some chapter numbers may miss. For example I start with the chapter 4 as you see in the image below:

[image]

I would like to have (4.1) as the number of the formula. If this is not possible, I agree to have it as (1.1). It is, however, numbered as (0.1).

Any idea of how to control the figure in the first position and, generally, how to fix this?

Comment: Can you put the notebook some place or include the notebook code in the question?

Comment: @user21 I hope this can be open The file is entitled ""Semiconductors (after Neamen)"

https://www.dropbox.com/l/scl/AAAPune3gBxsHzN5p6leZnhb3PrSxsSYd2g

Comment: I hope that I can share this file through the dropbox
https://www.dropbox.com/l/scl/AAAPune3gBxsHzN5p6leZnhb3PrSxsSYd2g
though they may ask to make an account. I am not sure.

Comment: Can we assume that chapter numbers are then assigned manually for each chapter?

Comment: @Kuba I also hypothesized this, but I do not know for sure.

Comment: You can do this with the various counter functions. I answered a question to this effect ~7 months ago but can’t find it quickly right now. They’re mostly undocumented but basically just work with `CounterBox`.